# Why do lvalue reference and rvalue reference collapse in lvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, value-categories

Let's consider this code:

```
int i=0;

using U = int&;
U&& x = i;

using V = int&&;
V& y = i;
```

Could you please explain the motivation for these two reference collapsing rules?

Comment: What other behaviour does make sense to you?

Comment: @n.m. I'm not sure what a combination of both kinds of refetence could mean at all...

Comment: Things that have no meaning normally result in compilation errors. Do you think a compilation error would be appropriate here?

Comment: @n.m. I need a better understanding this before deciding what is appropriate